# Spring Message Source XML Configuration Not Working

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm working to read messages on JSPs from message files by using spring message source bean definition in my application, I Know this could be a repeated question but I have tried many suggestions from other questions, I made the following steps

1. I Put the messages_en.properties and messages_ar.properties under
   src/main/resources.
2. Bean definition made on spring-core-config.xml file which was defined on the web.xml

   ```
   <bean id="messageSource"
   class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
   <property name="basename" value="classpath*:messages" />
   <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
   ```
3. Defined contextConfigLocation web.xml

   ```
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring-core-config.xml,
                    /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring-tx-config.xml,
                    /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring-security.xml
   </param-name>
   ```
4. The output of The WAR file contains the messages files on this path WEB-INF/classes
5. I'm using this line of code to read the key after importing the libs at the jsp page.

   ```
   <spring:message code = "${menubar.menu.dashboard}" />
   ```

I'm getting this error

> Jun 23, 2016 8:37:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/muras] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code '' for locale 'en_US'.] with root cause
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code '' for locale 'en_US'.
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doEndTag(MessageTag.java:200)
>       at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.home_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(home_jsp.java:647)
>       at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:528)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318).

please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get an error or a warning? If it's an error, can you post the whole stacktrace.

Comment: @Augusto it is an error and updated the question with full stack trace.

Comment: I guess it is unrelated though: ever tried to name the message file to `messages_en_US.properties` instead? I forgot the restrictions of using `classpath*:` in Spring. You may also try to put the file under `src/main/resources/msg/` directory, and set the `basename` as `classpath*:msg/messages`